# Who own the copyright of this game adapted anime music from "Sleepless: A Midsummer Night's Dream - The Animation" and "Jashin Shoukan"?

Tags: music, theme-song

**NSFW Warning: this question is related to hentai anime.**

A piece of music is used in different anime, namely ED of *Sleepless: A Midsummer Night's Dream - The Animation*, and the BGM starting from 11:50 in Ep. 2 of *Jashin Shoukan: Inran Kyonyuu Oyako Ikenie Gishiki*. The two anime have different producers and studios, the games have different developers. How can the music be used in both?

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [Who typically owns the rights to an anime's soundtrack?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/32238/2516)

Comment: Checking both credits, I only found 1 that is shared by both: [スワラプロ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BB%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD) as Sound FX Production (音響効果), but I don't know if this also extends to the BGM or not.